# Windows IoT Core Will Not Boot

Tags: boot-issues, windows-iot

Issue: Windows 10 IOT Core won't boot past the rainbow-pixel screen on the Raspberry Pi 3 model B+

Things I've tried:
-Using two different sd cards class 10 and 32gb size by Goodram and Kingston.
-Flashing cards from 3 different computers.
-Waiting on rainbow pixel screen for long time(all night).
-Changing power supply and cables.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently **3b+ is only supported by Build 17661** (as mentioned in the answer above), but more information about what's working and what isn't has become available from Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/troubleshooting?branch=master#raspberry-pi-3b-booting-issues

Answer (score 0):

Which version did you install?

You need at least preview build 17761 on a Pi3B+. See [RaspberryPi 3B+ Technical Preview Build 17661](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cd4a6d3-96e2-46de-8555-fae468962c52/raspberrypi-3b-technical-preview-build-17661?forum=WindowsIoT)

The most recent image can be downloaded at [Windows Insider Preview Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot), it's listed under additional downloads.

IIRC you will need an account to download that image.

Answer (score 0):

also note that it seems that you can only download the ISO if you are using Edge browser on Windows 10 - I wasted lots of time trying the download via Chrome on Ubuntu (I know the console only runs on Win 10 - but I have lots of machines) - dumb!